# RestSharp.Extension.MonoHttp not in version 106.10.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, restsharp

I use in visual studio the reference RestSharp.Extension.MonoHttp but when I update the RestSharp version from 105.2.3 to the version 106.10.1 the reference does not exist any more. an using RestSharp.Extension does not work and does not find anything to use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode

I can not find which alternative there is in RestSharp for unsing RestSharp.Extension.MonoHttp.

Comment: Which framework and version of .NET are you using?

Comment: This is a breaking [change between version 105 and 106](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/dev/releasenotes.md#10601) of RestSharp. Given that support has also been removed for .Net Framework 3.5 and 4.0 then it may be that 106 is not appropriate for your project

Comment: I use visual studio 2007 version 5.2.61435.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following library packages instead of the `RestSharp` for the HTTP Extension. They are

```
 - Postman
 - Amazon API Gateway 
 - Insomnia REST Client
 - OpenAPI
 - Paw
```